# After installing Ubuntu 20.04 the wifi card Ralink RT3090 does not see any wifi networks

Tags: wireless, 20.04, ralink

been having the problem above on two computers, one fixed itself somehow after a few days (it was connected to ethernet so maybe an update fixed it???)  The other had Ubuntu 20.04 installed a few days ago and again it seems to see the wifi card ok but the card cannot see my home wifi network or any others that it could see previously.  I have found some very old threads mentioning this card from many years ago and didn't want to mess with anything incase it made matters worse.
Could anyone explain how I can track down this issue / fix this issue?  The ethernet works ok on this. 
The other thing that just came to mind was when I installed Ubuntu on these two computers, during the installation it also didn't see any wifi networks and I had to install by selecting the ethernet for the downloads of updates.
Computer is an HP G5370UK

WiFi card info:

Network Controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Thanks for any help
Simon

Comment: Would very interesting to know, what kind of wifi card you have. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1238615/edit) your question and add the necessary data. You may use `lspci`to get it ...

Comment: You should login when you want to edit your question - now we have no way of knowing if that info really was from you :-))

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2372045) thread. Seems the kernel module for this WiFi chipset is available but not loaded in Ubuntu 20.04. Load it and set it to load on boot using these commands:

```
echo "options rt2800pci  nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt2800pci
```